# Elements in Grid Layout Form Won't Align

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm a newbie so please forgive the probably very silly question. I need to have the contact elements in my right grid column to be aligned with the form elements in the left column. So far the contact details just sit at the bottom and I can't figure out why.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
.form-list,
.form-contact {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.form-group {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.form-details {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-list">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="youremail@email.com" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" class="message-control" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="button">Contact us</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</main>

<div class="form-contact">
  <div class="form-details">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <p><span>456 Random Street,</span><span>Sydney,</span>
      <span>Australia</span></p>
    <p><span>Phone: 024 123 45678</span><span>Email: sales@website.co.nz</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) works, you need a wrapper or container that will display its content in a grid, what you did was put the `display: grid` on the elements themselves

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  align-items : flex-start;
}

.form-group {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.form-details {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.form-details h2 {
margin-top : 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-list">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control" required />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="youremail@email.com" class="form-control" required />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" class="message-control" required></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Contact us</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="form-contact">
    <div class="form-details">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <p><span>456 Random Street,</span><span>Sydney,</span>
        <span>Australia</span></p>
      <p><span>Phone: 024 123 45678</span><span>Email: sales@website.co.nz</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Made the edits -- nothing has happened except now everything is just in the left column

Comment: You must have failed something it works fine on the snippet :/

Comment: I need the contact to be at the same level as the "name" element line

Comment: It's just a margin issue from the h2 title, fixed it by removing margin-top from the title

Comment: I know it shows correct on the snippet, but on my end everything is just in the left column

Comment: Did you check your html for unclosed tags ? There were one or two in your original code I removed them from my snippet, be sure to remove the css that was unnecessary too

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all those css and just work with `flexbox`

```css
.form-list,
.form-contact {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<main>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-list">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="youremail@email.com" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" class="message-control" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="button">Contact us</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="form-contact">
  <div class="form-details">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <p><span>456 Random Street,</span><span>Sydney,</span>
      <span>Australia</span></p>
    <p><span>Phone: 024 123 45678</span><span>Email: sales@website.co.nz</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Made those changes and it's only made the elements mixed up

Comment: How means?can you explain or give a screenshot.?